# Standalone Python executable (compiled with PyInstaller) cannot pass through proxy, but when uncompiled source is executed everything works properly

Tags: python, python-requests, pyinstaller

I've compiled some python source code using PyInstaller on my Windows 10 machine with the goal of passing this .exe to end users who won't necessarily have Python installed on their computers. The source code uses the requests library to (1) pass through a corporate proxy, (2) authenticate on an openDAP server, and (3) download specified files.

When I run my code from source, in IPython, everything works perfectly. When I run the source code from the command line, again, everything works perfectly. But when I compile with PyInstaller and try to run the code from the generated executable, I receive the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                   
File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen                                                             
File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy                                                      
File "urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect                                                                 
File "urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in _new_conn                                                             
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 
0x000001E14DE48588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed 

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                   
File "requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send                                                                     
File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen                                                             
File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment                                                             
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<the correct host address was here>', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
<the correct opendap url was here> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E14DE48588>: Failed 
to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed'))) 

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                   
File "my_script_calls were here", line 29, in <module>                                                                                                                                            
File "requests\api.py", line 75, in get                                                                            
File "requests\api.py", line 61, in request                                                                        
File "requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request                                                                  
File "requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send                                                                     
File "requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send                                                                   
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<the correct host was here>', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
<the correct opendap url was here> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E14DE48588>: Failed 
to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed')))                                         
[23352] Failed to execute script my_script_was_here
```

Any troubleshooting help would be greatly appreciated. So far, I have:
(1) verified that PyInstaller is running in the correct python environment and with the correct python interpreter
(2) verified that this isn't an issue parsing configuration files to get proxy info (all parsed files are imported properly)
(3) not due to special characters in passwords (I've tried both ascii and URL-encoded)
(4) confirmed that the test cases work with uncompiled source code.

I note that my_script/build/warn-my_script.txt is packed full of missing modules. Attempted to pass paths to pyinstaller al a:

```
  PyInstaller --paths=path/to/my/env/Lib/site-packages --paths=path/to/my/env/Library/bin --onedir my_script.py
```

Alas, these modules are still not found by the Installer:

```
     missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed)
missing module named urllib.getproxies_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.urlencode - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), requests.utils (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
missing module named console - imported by pyreadline.console.ansi (conditional)
missing module named startup - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (conditional), pyreadline.keysyms.keysyms (conditional)
missing module named sets - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (optional)
missing module named System - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), pyreadline.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms (top-level), pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level), pyreadline.rlmain (conditional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by pyreadline.py3k_compat (conditional), urllib3.packages.six (conditional), six (conditional), simplejson.compat (conditional, optional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named IronPythonConsole - imported by pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level)
missing module named clr - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named Cookie - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named cookielib - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urlparse - imported by requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by simplejson.ordered_dict (top-level)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by simplejson.compat (conditional, optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cStringIO (top-level)
missing module named Queue - imported by urllib3.util.queue (conditional)
missing module named "'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib'.parse" - imported by urllib3.request (top-level), urllib3.poolmanager (top-level)
runtime module named urllib3.packages.six.moves - imported by http.client (top-level), urllib3.connectionpool (top-level), urllib3.util.response (top-level), 'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib' (top-level), urllib3.response (top-level), urllib3.util.queue (top-level)
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname (optional)
missing module named _abcoll - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict (optional)
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict (optional)
missing module named thread - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict (optional)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional)
missing module named 'typing.io' - imported by importlib.resources (top-level)
missing module named bcrypt - imported by cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.ssh (optional)
missing module named cryptography.x509.UnsupportedExtension - imported by cryptography.x509 (optional), urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (optional)
missing module named unicodedata2 - imported by charset_normalizer.hook (optional)
```

I know that many of these are obsolete modules requested by compatibility packages, so perhaps this isn't the source of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. I haven't figured out the root cause, but have determined it is due to problems with `ntpath.py`. I was trying to compile the program on a mounted network share. I noted, when trying to build a bare-bones conda environment to diagnose this problem that I couldn't install the requests module due to `ntpath.py` WinError 59.

```
  File "C:\Users\myuser\pyenv\lp38\lib\ntpath.py", line 601, in _getfinalpathname_nonstrict                               
  path = _getfinalpathname(path)                                                                                    
  OSError: [WinError 59] An unexpected network error occurred: 
 'H:\\my_path\\exec_prep\\my_script'
```

I relocated my project to my local drive, compiled the python code, and voila, it works as expected. Further testing indicates the executable must reside on a local drive and cannot be executed from the Microsoft Windows Network share drive.

How utterly frustrating.

Comment: I've had a similar issue running from a network drive with the pyinstaller/gooey combo. It didn't like UNC paths, but I could execute it if I used a non-UNC path for the network location.